# How to download azure Mobile App service project

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

How to download the azure Mobile App service project with all the apis folders, files and scripts?

I have a Mobile App service that I started using the node js as backend. I would like to make a copy of everything, files and scripts on the server and download it.

I would also like to be able to make some adjustments to the downloaded code offline and deploy it on another server at a later moment. Can it be done from the portal?

Comment: Have you tried FTP?

Comment: Yes, but I would like to do that from the portal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the portal, you can download a copy of your app by launching the Kudu tools (App Service's **Advanced Tools** menu).  In Kudu:

- Select the **Debug Console/CMD** menu
- Navigate to the **site** folder
- Click on the download icon to the left of the **wwwroot** folder

This will download a zipped copy of the folder.

Answer (score 0):

We can edit the Files in  App Service Editor too now directly from the azure portal. Its in preview.  [App Service Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRRJO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

We can edit the Files in App Service Editor too now directly from the azure portal. Its in preview. App use to vivo Android to windows phone only

Comment: Please advise that a good practice is to update code at it's source as opposed to a live production instance.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).